# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt

Tags: apache

I just tried to install apache 2.4.25 with these configure parameters

```
 ./configure --prefix=/opt/apache2/ --with-apr=/opt/apr --with-apr-util=/opt/apr-util --with-pcre=/opt/pcre  --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
```

and seems no problem. But when I tried to make, it halted and says

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt
```

Then I tried to find out whether libcrypt* library is loaded, and yes is there

```
[root@localhost httpd-2.4.25]# ldconfig -p | grep libcrypt
        libcryptui.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libcryptui.so.0
        libcryptsetup.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libcryptsetup.so.1
        libcrypto.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10
        libcrypto.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1
        libcrypto.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so
        libcrypt.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.18) => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1
        libcrypt.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.18) => /usr/lib64/libcrypt.so.1
```

Any clue about this?

Comment: failing line from make please?

Comment: /opt/apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -pthread         -o httpd  modules.lo buildmark.o -export-dynamic server/libmain.la modules/core/libmod_so.la modules/http/libmod_http.la server/mpm/event/libevent.la os/unix/libos.la -L/opt/pcre/lib -lpcre     /opt/apr-util/lib/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat /opt/apr/lib/libapr-1.la -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [httpd] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/src/httpd-2.4.25'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: perhaps it's looking for libcrypt.a ? http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/help-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lcrypt-926640/